# Unable to redirect the user in the webview with source passed in the url

Tags: android, android-studio, redirect, webview, android-webview

I am using android webview to open a URL in my app. I want the webview to handle all the redirects in the webview itself without looking for a browser. I have implemented it by creating a `webViewClient` and overriding the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method.

The URL should redirect the user to login page if `source=android_apps` is passed with the URL
But the webview is not handling the redirect to the login page instead it open a popup dialog with signin options that is expected to occur when the `source=android_apps` is not passed

**Code for reference**

```
wv_content.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                handleCurrentUrl(url)
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(url)
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
                val uri: Uri = request.getUrl()
                return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(uri.toString())
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                pb_loading.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            private fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(url: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })

        wv_content.loadUrl(url)
    }
```

I have also checked by running the same URL in the chrome mWeb and it is working as expected but not in the mobile webview. Is there a possibility that mobile webview doesn't admire the source passed with the URL?

I have tried all the possible solutions available for similar tasks but no one is working. Looking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled javascript on your webview? I have found sometimes if the webview cant handle elements on the page if kicks the url out

Comment: Yes it is enabled